# Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":[],"statusText":"Bad Request"} only on Safari Browser

Tags: angular, promise, angular6

Getting Below error on Angular Application on PUT method call on Safari Browser ,But same working fine on Chrome Browser .

```
 returnData = await this.http.put(applicationUrl, formattedData).toPromise(); 

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) 
       (pixel, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) 
   (setuid, line 0)
 [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (11929, line 0)
 [Error] Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: 
 {"headers":{"normalizedNames":[],"lazyUpdate":null},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","url":"http://localhost:4200/api/application/11929","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure
```